# Angular directives stop working halfway down the page

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, ngfor

I have an Angular Reactive Form on a page, and some Angular functions stop working after a **br** about halfway down the page. My **mat-card-title** no longer shows up, and an *ngFor loop no longer displays data. If I move the *ngFor loop up the page (anywhere before the **mat-card** that's after the **br**) it works just fine.

I've tried putting a simple **li *ngFor=....** in every section below the **br** and it doesn't work anywhere. I have several arrays to loop through - none of them work. The only error I get in the console is "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" - because the first ngFor loop (factionGAs) does not get populated. I actually see that it reserves four slots (there are four items in the array), but doesn't put the data in.

HTML:

```
      <div id="uploader" class="uploader">
  <div [hidden]="submitted" class="card-body">
    <mat-card id="heading"  ([ngModel])="playerSub">
      <h3>Entering Results as:</h3>
      <h4>{{player.username}}</h4>
    </mat-card>
    <br>
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title>Find opponent:</mat-card-title>
      <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="findPlayers()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select placeholder="Search by:" class="form-control" 
 formControlName="searchBy">
            <option [value]="null">Search by:</option>
            <option value="playerId">Player ID</option>
            <option value="email">Email address</option>
            <option value="username">Username</option>
          </select>
          <input *ngIf="searchQuery.includes('playerId')" class="form- 
 control" type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter Player ID" formControlName="playerId" />
          <input *ngIf="searchQuery.includes('email')" class="form-control" 
type="text" 
            placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="email" />
          <input *ngIf="searchQuery.includes('username')" class="form- 
control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" 
formControlName="username"/>
        </div>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </form>
      <mat-card-footer *ngIf="playerList" ([ngModel])="playerList"> 
{{playerList.username}}</mat-card-footer>
  </mat-card>
  <br>
  <mat-card *ngIf="playerFound" style="text-align: center">
  <mat-card-title>Enter your results: </mat-card-title>  
  <form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="submitGame()">
  <mat-card-content>
  <div class="card-group" style="margin: auto 10% auto 10%">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title>{{player.username}}'s Results:</mat-card-title>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="P1GA">
            <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Select Grand Alliance: 
 </option>
            <option *ngFor="let ga of factionGAs" value="ga.value"> 
 {{ga.name}}</option>
          </select>
          <select *ngIf="P1GA.name.includes('Order')" 
 formControlName="playerOneFaction" class="form-control">
            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>
            <option *ngFor="let sf of orderFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
 </option>
          </select>
          <select *ngIf="P1GA.name.includes('Destruction')" 
formControlName="playerOneFaction" class="form-control">
            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>  
            <option *ngFor="let sf of desFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
</option>
            </select>
          <select *ngIf="P1GA.name.includes('Chaos')" 
formControlName="playerOneFaction" class="form-control">
            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>
            <option *ngFor="let sf of chaosFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
</option>
          </select>
          <select *ngIf="P1GA.name.includes('Death')" 
formControlName="playerOneFaction" class="form-control">
            <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>
            <option *ngFor="let sf of deathFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
 </option>
          </select>
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="playerOneResult" 
 required>
            <option [ngValue]="null">Select your result:</option>
            <option *ngFor="let result of results" [value]="result"> 
 {{result}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card ([ngModel])="playerList">
      <mat-card-title>{{playerList.username}}'s Results:</mat-card-title>
      <div class="form-group">
          <select placeholder="Select Grand Alliance" class="form-control" 
formControlName="P2GA">
              <option [ngValue]="null">Select Grand Alliance:</option>
              <option *ngFor="let ga of factionGAs" [value]="ga">{{ga.name}} 
</option>
            </select>
            <select *ngIf="P2GA.name.includes('Order')" 
formControlName="playerTwoFaction" class="form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>
              <option *ngFor="let sf of orderFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
</option>
            </select>
            <select *ngIf="P2GA.name.includes('Destruction')" 
formControlName="playerTwoFaction" class="form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>  
              <option *ngFor="let sf of desFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
</option>
              </select>
            <select *ngIf="P2GA.name.includes('Chaos')" 
formControlName="playerTwoFaction" class="form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>
              <option *ngFor="let sf of chaosFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
</option>
            </select>
            <select *ngIf="P2GA.name.includes('Death')" 
formControlName="playerTwoFaction" class="form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="null">Select Faction:</option>
              <option *ngFor="let sf of deathFactions" [value]="sf">{{sf}} 
</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="playerTwoResult" 
required>
              <option [ngValue]="null">Select your result:</option>
              <option *ngFor="let result of results" [value]="result"> 
{{result}}</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
    <mat-card style="align-content: center" width="60%">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select formControlName="battlePlan" class="form-control" 
 required>
              <option [value]="null">Select Battleplan:</option>
              <option *ngFor="let plan of battleplans" [value]="plan"> 
 {{plan}}</option>
          </select>
           <select class="form-control" formControlName="pointsLevel" 
 required>
            <option [value]="null">Select points level:</option>
            <option value="1000">1000</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-card-content>

  <br>
  <mat-card-actions>        

      <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
      <button class="button" (click)="toggleEditForm()">{{ editBtnText }} 
</button>
      <input type="button" name="Review" value="History">

  </mat-card-actions>
</form> 
  </mat-card>
  </div>
    <br>
<mat-card *ngIf="submitted" ([ngModel])="formSub">
    <mat-card-title>You submitted the following:</mat-card-title>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Faction: </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">{{formSub.playerOneFaction}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Battleplan: </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">{{formSub.battlePlan}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Result: </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9">{{formSub.playerOneResult}}</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button class="button" (click)="submitted=false">Edit</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '@/_services/authentication.service';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormControl } from 
'@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Games } from '@/_services/games.service';
import { Rank } from '@/_services/rank.service';
import { Game } from '@/_models/games';
import { Player } from '@/_models/players';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FilterSortService } from '@/_services/filter-sort.service';
import { OrderFactions, DesFactions,
          ChaosFactions, DeathFactions, BattlePlans } from '@/_models/data- 
arrays';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() gameId: number;

  showEditForm = false;
  editBtnText: string;
  playerGame: Game;
  gamesSub: Subscription;
  loggedInSub: Subscription;
  routeSub: Subscription;
  playerSub: Subscription;
  games: Game[];
  id: number;
  playerOne: number;
  playerTwo: number;
  player: Player = new Player;
  gameCheck: Game = new Game;
  playerListSub: Subscription
  searchQuery: string[] = [];
  playerList: Player = new Player;
  playerFound = true;
  filteredPlayers: Player[];
  factionGAs = [
    { name: 'Chaos', value: 'chaosRank' },
    { name: 'Death', value: 'deathRank' },
    { name: 'Destruction', value: 'desRank' },
    { name: 'Order', value: 'orderRank' }
  ]
  P1GA: string[] = [];
  P2GA: string[] = [];
  orderFactions = OrderFactions;
  chaosFactions = ChaosFactions;
  desFactions = DesFactions;
  deathFactions = DeathFactions;
  battleplans = BattlePlans;
  results = [
    'Major Victory', 'Minor Victory',
    'Minor Loss', 'Major Loss', 'Draw'
  ]
  players: Player[];
  loading: boolean;
  error: boolean;
  query: '';
  submitted = false;
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  uploadForm: FormGroup;
  formSub: Subscription;
  message: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, public auth: AuthService, public game: 
 Games,
              private rank: Rank, public fs: FilterSortService, private 
 route: ActivatedRoute,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this._getGames();
    this.toggleEditForm(false);
    this._getPlayerList();
    this.loggedInSub = this.auth.currentUser.subscribe(loggedIn => {
      this.loading = true;
      if (loggedIn) {
        this._routeSubs();
      }
    });
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      searchBy: null,
      playerId: null,
      email: null,
      username: null
    });
    this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      playerOne: null,
      playerTwo: null,
      playerOneResult: [null, Validators.required],
      playerTwoResult: [null, Validators.required],
      battlePlan: [null, Validators.required],
      pointsLevel: [null, Validators.required],
      P1GA: null,
      P2GA: null,
      playerOneFaction: [null, Validators.required],
      playerTwoFaction: [null, Validators.required],
      playerOneList: [null, Validators.required],
      playerTwoList: [null, Validators.required]
    });
    this.uploadForm.get('P1GA').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.P1GA = [];
      this.P1GA.push(value);
    });
    this.uploadForm.get('P2GA').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.P2GA = [];
      this.P2GA.push(value);
    });
    this.searchForm.get('searchBy').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.searchQuery = [];
      this.searchQuery.push(value);
    })
  }

  private _routeSubs() {
    // set playerId from route params and subscribe
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['playerId'];
      this._getPlayer();
    });
  }

  private _getPlayer() {
    this.loading = true;
    // Get player by playerID
    this.playerSub = this.rank.getPlayer(this.id).subscribe(res =>{
      this.player = res;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    err => {
      console.error(err);
      this.loading = false;
      this.error = true;
    });
  }

  toggleEditForm(setVal?: boolean) {
    this.showEditForm = setVal !== undefined ? setVal : !this.showEditForm;
    this.editBtnText = this.showEditForm ? 'Cancel Edit' : 'Edit Last Game';
  }

  private _getGames() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.gamesSub = this.game.getGame(this.gameId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.games = res;
        this.loading = false;
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.loading = false;
        this.error = true;
      });
  }

  private _getPlayerList() {
    this.loading = true;
    // Get future, public events
    this.playerListSub = this.rank
      .getPlayers()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.playerList = res;
          this.filteredPlayers = res;
          this.loading = false;
        },
        err => {
          console.error(err);
          this.loading = false;
          this.error = true;
        }
      );
  }



  get s() {return this.searchForm.controls;}

  findPlayers() {
    if (this.searchForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    let formValue = this.searchForm.value;

    for (let prop in formValue) {
      if (!formValue[prop]) {
        delete formValue[prop];
      }
      if (formValue.searchBy) {
        delete formValue.searchBy;
      }
      if (Array.isArray(formValue[prop])) {
        let resultArray = formValue[prop].filter((item: any) => item);
        if (resultArray.length > 0 ) {
          formValue[prop] = resultArray;
        }
      }
    }
    this.rank.findPlayer(formValue)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.playerList = result;
        console.log(result);
        this.playerFound = true;
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
      });    
  }

  submitGame() {

    this.uploadForm.controls['playerOne'].setValue(this.player.playerId);

  this.uploadForm.controls['playerTwo'].setValue(this.playerList.playerId);

    //console.log(this.uploadForm.value);
    this.game.upload(this.uploadForm.value)
      .subscribe();
    this.submitted = true;
    this.formSub = this.uploadForm.value;
  }

  onSubmitGame(e: any) { 
    if (e.game) {
      this.playerGame = e.game;
      this.toggleEditForm(false);
    }}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.playerListSub.unsubscribe();
    this.gamesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.playerSub.unsubscribe();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please, can you start a new Angular project on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) so that we can see your question in action ?

Comment: Not sure it'll work great, since it's a huge project, but can try this:
https://stackblitz.com/github/foolsama/AoSELO

Comment: I can't open it, stackblitz complains that something went wrong with this repository...

Comment: Yea, it's not even really going to be too helpful without the back end, too.. can try and clone the repository?
https://github.com/foolsama/AoSELO